# How to open QGIS project without being asked for PostGIS credentials every time

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql, spatial-database, authentication

**Problem:**
We have several layers stored in a `PostgreSQL` database with `PostGIS` extension (Stored on `AWS RDS` Instance).
 The connection has been working perfectly to date.
I get asked for login credentials every time I open the `QGIS 3.16.5` project which is stored locally.

**What I'd like to happen:**
I'd like to open the QGIS project and have the layers loaded from `PostgreSQL`+ `PostGIS` database without needing to authenticate every time.

**Why it's important:**

1. Saves time every time we open a project
2. Multiple database connections means entering credentials for every database connection
3. I'd like to know how to improve the UX for our users

**What I have tried:**

1. Stored credentials as plain text in the project file `Edit PostGIS Connection > Authentication > Basic > Check Store checkbox`
2. Converted to configuration. `Edit PostGIS Connection > Authentication > Configurations > Create Authentication Configuration > Fill in Authentication Dialog inputs`

**Resources I've looked at already:**

1. https://issues.qgis.org/issues/21582
2. [From QGIS 3.4.5 and 3.6 asks password repeadly to connect to PostgreSQL 10](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/314723/from-qgis-3-4-5-and-3-6-asks-password-repeadly-to-connect-to-postgresql-10)
3. https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/auth_system/index.html?highlight=authentication
4. [Change in PostGIS database password prompts for user credentials on QGIS start](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/321447/change-in-postgis-database-password-prompts-for-user-credentials-on-qgis-start)
5. [QGIS asks for PostgreSQL credentials multiple times](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/321255/qgis-asks-for-postgresql-credentials-multiple-times)

**Questions:**

1. Is this a known bug with the `3.16-LTR`, if so where can I find out more?
2. Am I managing the connections incorrectly or overlooking something?

**Environment:**
OS - `Windows 10 Professional`
QGIS Version - `3.16.5-Hannover`

Comment: Are you using pgpass? https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/331053/save-postgis-login-informations-in-qgis

Comment: No, but it sounds like a good idea to. I read the article. Thank you for the link! 
There is a note there on security "NB : it's not safe to use it this way but it's ok if it's a local database." Do you know a safer way to store credentials?

Answer (score 10):

A very good solution is to use a [connection service file](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-pgservice.html).

Using this, you can have your credentials in one file, completely independent of QGIS.

You can share the project. Other users can use the same project as well, using their own credentials.

The same project can be used by QGIS Server, using other credentials as well.

And you can start saving your projects in the database.

### On Windows

Since you are using Windows, you need **three steps** to get *pg service* files working.

#### Set PGSYSCONFDIR

On your local computer, you must set the environment variable `PGSYSCONFDIR` pointing to the folder where you want to store your `pg_service.conf` file.

Usually, this can go to your home folder, like in the following print screen.

[image]

#### Create your own pg_service.conf

After setting `PGSYSCONFDIR`, create a text file called `pg_service.conf` with your authentication details. The file will look like this:

```
[neverland]
host=postgresql.neverland.com
port=5432
dbname=neverland
user=peter
password=wendy
```

This creates a new service called `neverland`. You can create as many as you like.

#### Use pg services in QGIS

After setting `PGSYSCONFDIR` and create your own `pg_service.conf` file, you can start using this authentication method in QGIS.

You just need to enter the service name in the New PostGIS Connection dialogue.

[image]

Comment: thanks for the detailed explanation! Appreciate it. This answer is the more maintainable solution I was looking for.